# YIU and AJAX pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, yui

Is there AJAX pagination for YIU framework?
I tried [Paginator View](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/paginator-view), but it looks like it pages data without AJAX. To my understanding there is single request which fetches the whole result-set which is broken down by pages afterwards, but what if there are few millions of rows?

*Here is my data sample:*

```
{
    totalItems: 1231313,
    itemsPerPage: 6,
    page: 1,
    users: [
        {
            userid: "Jf9CEy70",
            password: "g5JY9OB2",
            status_id: 1,
            expire_account: "2004-01-13 00:00:00",
            created: "2014-01-13 18:33:25"
        },
        {
            userid: "8LZVQX6b",
            password: "QFzO92tM",
            status_id: 1,
            expire_account: "2014-01-22 00:00:00",
            created: "2014-01-13 18:35:00"
        },
        {
            userid: "cItWduq9",
            password: "SuzcWisl",
            status_id: 0,
            expire_account: "0014-01-13 00:00:00",
            created: "2014-01-13 18:35:21"
        },
        {
            userid: "7QpP7Y7X",
            password: "Sp4p2EDB",
            status_id: 1,
            expire_account: "0014-01-13 00:00:00",
            created: "2014-01-13 18:36:31"
        },
        {
            userid: "NMr4U3Ei",
            password: "mC1s4RYb",
            status_id: 1,
            expire_account: "0014-01-13 00:00:00",
            created: "2014-01-13 18:40:48"
        },
        {
            userid: "qMjbSj7m",
            password: "h0QDpr2h",
            status_id: 1,
            expire_account: "0014-01-13 00:00:00",
            created: "2014-01-13 18:43:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

*And this is JS code:*

```
    YUI(
        {gallery: 'gallery-2013.01.16-21-05'}
    ).use(
        'gallery-datatable-paginator'
        , 'gallery-paginator-view'
        , 'datasource-io'
        , 'datasource-jsonschema'
        , 'datatable-base'
        , 'datatable-datasource'
        , 'datatable-scroll' 
        , function (Y) {
            var cols = [    
                { key: 'userid',    label: 'UserId'  }, 
                { key: 'password',  label: 'Password'  },
                { key: 'status_id', label: 'Status'  },
                { key: 'created',   label: 'Created'  },
            ];
            var url = '/app_dev.php/partner/api/users';
            var ds  = new Y.DataSource.IO({ 
                source:url
            });
            ds.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
                schema: {resultListLocator: 'users'}
            });
            var pmodel = new Y.PaginatorModel({
                page:           1,
                itemsPerPage:   6,
                totalItems:     500
            });
            var dt = new Y.DataTable(
                {
                    columnset: cols
                    , paginator: new Y.PaginatorView({
                        model:              pmodel,
                        container:          '#pagBasicCCont',
                    })
                    , paginatorResize: true
                    , paginationSource: 'remote'
                }
            ).plug(
                Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource
                , {datasource: ds}
            );
            dt.render('#data-tbl');
            dt.datasource.load();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/datatable-paginator works very well for server-side pagination. Unfortunately, the docs and examples seem to be offline, but it is worth persevering with. Do you have the ability to set up what your paginated JSON data looks like?

The plugin expects data like this;

```
{
 totalItems:12931,
 itemsPerPage: 20,
 page:3,
 results:
 [
   {data record 1},
   {data record 2}
 }
}
```

Which kind of makes sense, as the pagination needs that metadata in order to render the pagination for you.

I can't find contact details for the author, which is a pity, as it'd be really handy if the examples were available. If I get a chance i'll get a basic example online and link it here.

Comment: The question was updated  with data sample. I have created Restful API already. It could be queried with `page` query parameter. BTW, I also use `DataTable`, but with no paging so far. I seen this link before. What is `#tmpl-bar` should it be created by me? As I had an error on this line. Why uis it called gallery?

Comment: The JSON you provided, should it be the output of API or it's `DataTable` configuration?

Comment: that should be the output of the API. At work we use it with ModelList.

Comment: Do you have YUI example for remote pagination? I have updated the question with JS code and new Server output. So far, I was not able to make it as `remote`.